# JavaScript, return function callback in a async function

Tags: javascript, middy

Is there any kind of performance problem by returning a `callback` function in a `async` function as this code?:

```
import middy from '@middy/core';
import someFunction from 'someFunction';

async function testFunction (
  args,
  callback
) {
  // code
  const data = await someFunction();

  return callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
}

export const handler = middy(testFunction);
```

I'm using [Middy](https://github.com/middyjs/middy) library, I don't think it's relevant to say but just in case.

Comment: You are not returning a callback function, you are executing a function named `callback` and returning its return value. Also, `async` is unneeded as you do not `await`.

Comment: "*Middy allows you to return promises or throw errors from your handlers (instead of calling `callback()`) and middlewares (instead of calling `next()`).*" - that means you should use **either**. Not both. A function returning a promise with the result should never call a callback with that result.

Comment: @crashmstr you are right. I edited the question (I actually need async)

Comment: @Bergi that's what was I thinking (or something), I'm not sure how should I proceed

Comment: Just drop the `callback` and `return` the result directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a promise **or** use callback.

```js
const testFunction = async (event, context) => {
  // ... other logic
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }
}
```

This is a common pain point with new comers to middy. This has been addressed in middy v2 with the deprecation of callbacks altogether.

Comment: middy v2? ahh good, that's pretty new https://github.com/middyjs/middy/tree/release/2.x

Comment: I wrote it over the holidays. I hope to have an alpha out this month.